# 2010 Nissan Altima making noise, possible electrical that no one can help with.

Tags: electrical, noise, nissan, alternator, altima

Our 2010 Nissan Altima started making strange noises-sounds like knocking under the hood, especially when idling.  No one can tell us what it is, when hooked up it doesn't register anything.  I have been to a trusted mechanic and the dealership.  I don't know it is connected but for the past several years my radio display would work some days but not others. The radio works, just not the display. Now we have noticed that even though we have our headlights on auto, our tail lights don't always work.  The brake light works but if the lights are on then tail lights should be on.  I originally thought a fuse for the radio but now I think there is more of a problem.  I would appreciate any thoughts or sucggestions

Comment: What did the dealership and/or the trusted mechanic have to say about it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!